# C++: Keep getting SIGSEV signal and segmentation fault whenever I try running this char pointer function

Tags: c++, pointers, char

I've just started learning about pointers and am currently having trouble with this function that I'm suppose to analyze since it does not seem to be compiling for me.

```
void mystery3(char *str1, char *str2)
{
  while(*str1 != 0)
  {
    str1++;
  }
  while(*str2 != 0)
  {
    *str1 = *str2;
    str1++;
    str2++;
  }
  *str1 = *str2;
}
```

I've tried different ways to implement the function but I keep getting errors or null pointers in the end. Here's the driver I'm currently using:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
  char str, str2;
  char *strPtr, *strPtr2;


  str = 'a';
  strPtr = &str;
  str2 = 'b';
  strPtr2 = &str2;

  cout << (int*)strPtr << " " << (int*)strPtr2 << endl;
  cout << strPtr << " " << strPtr2 << endl;
  cout << *strPtr << " " << *strPtr2 << endl;
  mystery3(strPtr, strPtr2);
  cout << (int*)strPtr << " " << (int*)strPtr2 << endl;
  cout << strPtr << " " << strPtr2 << endl;

  return 0;
}
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated! I've been stuck on this for a while.

EDIT:
Thank you all for the help! I've fixed the issue now, and understand what I was doing wrong.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is that you are having pointer to a single character, which in itself is not a string. A string in C is a set of one or more characters, *terminated by a zero* (the character `'\0'`). Since the "strings" you pass to the functions are not terminated, your loops will go beyond the end of the data pointed to by the pointers, probably by quite a lot.

Then you you write to the pointers, which by now are way beyond the memory allocated for the data, thereby causing [*undefined behavior*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Undefined_behavior) which often leads to crashes.

To solve this you should pass in arrays of appropriate length, meaning that the second array have to be longer than the first one.

Answer (score 2):

The problem is with the usage of the `mystery3` function: it assumes several things which are not true:

- **`str1` points to a region of characters terminating in `'\0'`** - This is not true: `str1` points to a single non-zero character, with no zero termination after it
- **`str2` points to a region of characters terminating in `'\0'`** - Same as above
- **`str1` points to a region of memory sufficient to store strings at `str1` and `str2`, and a single null terminator** - This is not true: `str1` points to a single character.

To fix this, you need to allocate enough memory for the concatenated string (say, by using an array) and initialize both arrays with null-terminated strings. Make this change in the `main` function:

```
char strPtr[10] = "a";
char strPtr2[] = "b";
```

This will produce the expected result.

[Demo on ideone.](http://ideone.com/856Y9z)

Comment: Thank you for the quick and detailed response! That makes a lot of sense.